# Javascript redirect inside PHP does not show the message

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, alert

I want to show a message to the user, then redirect to another page 
I saw many questions about this point here and I tried the suggested solutions and this is one of them:

```
echo "<script>document.writeln('Redirecting you soon');
setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://www.forobd2.com';\",2000);</script>";
```

But this just redirect you the the page and the message does not show.
I devided the message into two statements and nothing have changed.

Comment: Are you sure it's not writing the message to the document?  Is it perhaps just writing it outside of any meaningfully displayed DOM element?  It's usually better to output the message into the DOM rather than just writing it out like this.

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`, the first argument should be a callback function. Strings work, but it's not recommended. That, and `document.writeln` is probably a bug. Don't use `document.write` or `writeln`, because the `document` is in a closed state. That and `document.writeln` is not supported in XHTML

Comment: @David You are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
echo "<script>document.writeln('Redirecting you soon');
setTimeout(function(){location.href = 'http://www.forobd2.com';},2000);</script>";
```